# Mouseover shop scroll effect

Tags: html, scroll, containers, mouseover

I would like to include the mouseover 'Shop Now' effect on my images, I used this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.container {
    style= "width:300px;height:300px;"
    left: 0;
    Right: 0;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" >
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Shop Now</div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</html>
```

But when I run it on my site the scroll effect works for all 3 images at the same time. As shown below:
[image]

What can I do to solve this problem? I have been told previously that if I change the container size to just fit the image it should work, but how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.container {
    width:300px; /*edited here*/
    height:300px;
    /*this syntax is for html tags ONLY: style= "width:300px;height:300px;"*/

    left: 0;
    Right: 0;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" >
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">Shop Now</div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</html>
```

you used the wrong syntax for css. style= "width:300px;height:300px;" would be correct if it was in your html like so:

```html
<div class = "container" style= "width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
```

but in css the style is already implied throught the  tags so in css all you need to do is:

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    /*and so on*/
}
```

note: to avoid future problems learn about chrome's inspect tool. It will help you get a better understanding of your page layout and the size of elements and what not. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Answer (score 0):

Few short notes:

U cannot use *style= "width:300px;height:300px;"* within css. Within your example, your first line should be:

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    left:0;
    Right:0;
}
```

You can only use the style-attribute within your html, but it is not nessesairy. If you do this, it will bypass your css:

```
<div class="container" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
```

You furthermore don't really have to call width and height both, since an image will scale automatically when it has one of these.

With all this being said, I believe this code solves your problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  width: 200px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: green; /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Overlay Title</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">Shop now</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">Shop now</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```